# how can I solve this error "Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results."?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to push my flutter app to apple developer account with xcode.When I run project on Visual studio code ,it works without any proplem.However wehenever I archieve app on xcode I get this error. For better understanding I attach the screenshoot of error: [image]

Almost I tried each solution on stackoverflow,but none of them helped.Maybe I missed some parts